# Why can't Anaconda python in shebang line find script (cygwin)?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, cygwin

I use cygwin on Windows 10, and want to write Python code
that uses Pandas and other packages contained in my Anaconda base
environment.  I can run Python code if I give the absolute
path to the code, but not if bash needs to use PATH
to find the code.

I use these lines in my .bash_profile as suggested 
[here](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell) (search for 'bash_profile'):

```
. /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
```

Here's the start of my PATH, showing Anaconda stuff at the front:

```
$ echo ${PATH:1:160}
cygdrive/c/Users/Glenn/Anaconda3:/cygdrive/c/Users/Glenn/Anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/Glenn/Anaconda3/Library/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/Gle...
```

I can run Anaconda Python at the bash prompt:

```
$ which python
/cygdrive/c/Users/Glenn/Anaconda3/python
$ python -i
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I can even run a Python program that uses Pandas:

```
$ pwd
/home/Glenn/bin
$ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
print(pd.Series([1,2]))
$ ./test.py
0    1
1    2
dtype: int64
```

The problem is that I can't run the program if I rely on the path:

```
$ which test.py
/home/Glenn/bin/test.py
$ test.py
C:\Users\Glenn\Anaconda3\python.exe: can't open file '/home/Glenn/bin/test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
$
```

I get the same kind of error message if I invoke test.py from
another directory using an absolute pathname, but not if I invoke
it using a relative pathname.

I'm a longtime Cygwin user and haven't seen this kind of behavior
before, so suspect it has to do with Anaconda.
I can change to any other directory and get the same behavior.
Also, if I put the absolute path to Anaconda's Python in the
shebang line, I get the same behavior.

I've found (and tried) many suggestions for configuring Anaconda in a Cygwin environment, but many of them are 4 or 5 years old.

UPDATE: I was not able to solve this problem, but have switched to the Linux Windows Subsystem and no longer have to deal with the issue.

Comment: FWIW I've struggled with this recently too.  Anaconda is quite buggy on Cygwin.  It's been on my todo list to submit some fixes, as there's no reason it shouldn't be usable in a Cygwin shell.

Comment: "The problem is that I can't run the program if I rely on the path:"  This is sort of a separate issue, but the executables in Anaconda for Windows don't know about Cygwin and thus don't know how to handle UNIX-style paths in Cygwin.  In some cases, Cygwin is smart enough to convert Cygwin paths to native Windows paths when passing them as arguments to Windows programs, but it doesn't always work.  You need to use the `cygpath` utility to convert them to Windows paths for use with Windows programs.